# IDX condition in a getresource tpl

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources, modx-templates, modx-chunks

I use getresource like this:

```
[[!getResources? &tpl=`coffrets_id` &parents=`1115`]]
```

inside `coffrets_id` tpl I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
[[+idx:is=`1`:then=`show only first getressrouce result`:else=``]]
[[+idx:is=`2`:then=`show only second getressrouce result`:else=``]]
[[+idx:is=`3`:then=`show only third getressrouce result`:else=``]]...
```

but I have no idea how to show only the result that matches the idx. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just use  [Templating Properties](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources#getResources-TemplatingProperties)

```
[[!getResources? 
    &tpl=`coffrets_id` 
    &tpl_1=`coffrets_id_1` 
    &tpl_2=`coffrets_id_2` 
    &tpl_3=`coffrets_id_3` 
    &parents=`1115`
]]
```